# Preventing Marionette CompositeView render until fetch complete

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm having a problem where render is being called autimatically in my `Marionette CompositeView` which is correct, the problem is that I'm fetching collection data in the `initialize` and want this to be present when the render happens. At the moment I'm running `this.render()` inside the done method of the fetch which re-renders but this causes problems as now I have 2 views per model. Can anyone recommend how I can properly prevent this initial render or prevent the duplicate views. 1 entry will output view1 and view2.

**JS CompositeView**

```
initialize: function() {
            var self = this;

            this.teamsCollection = new TeamsCollection();

            this.teamsCollection.fetch().done(function() {
                self.render();
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't believe there is a way to stop rendering outright, but you have a bunch ways around that.

Option 1: fetch data first, then create your view and pass data into it when it's done.

```
//before view is rendered, this is outside of your view code.
var teamsCollection = new TeamsCollection();

teamsCollection.fetch().done(function(results) {
    var options = {res: results};
    var myView = new CompositeView(options);
    myView.setElement( /* your element here */ ).render();
});
```

Option 2:

```
// don't use render method, use your own
initialize: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.teamsCollection = new TeamsCollection();

    this.teamsCollection.fetch().done(function() {
        self.doRender();
    });
},
render: function(){}, // do nothing
doRender: function(){
    // override render here rather than using default
}
```

Option 3: (if using template)

```
// if you have a template, then you can simply pass in a blank one on initialization
// then when the fetch is complete, replace the template and call render again
initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.template = "<div></div"; // or anything else really
    this.teamsCollection = new TeamsCollection();

    this.teamsCollection.fetch().done(function() {
        self.template = /* my template */;
        self.render();
    });
},
```

In reality I need more info. How is the view created? is it a region? is it added dynamically on the fly? Do you use templates? Can you provide any more code?

Comment: Thanks for this, yeah this is created dynamically and uses regions! I do indeed use templates and like the idea of your option 3. I'll update my question with some more info

Comment: Hmmm actually the third option doesnt get away from the fact that double views are being created for each model as the render will still happen twice per model?

Comment: Well, I hope my answer pointed you in the right direction at least. But using the regions means you want Marionette to automatically render things for you, so your only option is to render something invisible and with a class that doesn't do anything (first render). Then once you get data, switch the class and template and re-render.